# Iterate and save cursor - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have this array in MongoDB:

[image]

I want to iterate and make queries on it:

```
> for(var i=0; i < AllegriTeams.length; i++) {a[i]=db.team.find({
_id:AllegriTeams[i].team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})}
```

The array a, at the end of for cycle, contains just the first two official names. I lose the last official_name.

Comment: can you please elaborate bit more on your question ? Also post the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop looks correct and it is not clear why you would not receive three items in your array `a`.

**Check that your variable `AllegriTeams` has three elements.**

```
> AllegriTeams.length
3
```

I mimicked your setup and I received the results you expected where `a` has three elements. Here's what I did:

```
// 1. Log into mongo and use the "test" database, for example
> use test 

// 2. Create data
> db.team.insert({"_id": "Juv.26", "official_name":"Juv.26.xxx”})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.team.insert({"_id": "Mil.74", "official_name":"Mil.74.xxx”})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.team.insert({"_id": "Cag.00", "official_name":"Cag.00.xxx”})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

// 3. Create the AllegriTeams variable
> var AllegriTeams = [ { "team_id":"Juv.26"}, {"team_id":"Mil.74"}, {"team_id":"Cag.00"}]

// 4. Create the "a" array
> var a = []

// 5. Run the for loop. Consider using "findOne" instead of "find".
> for (var i=0; i < AllegriTeams.length; i++) { a[i]=db.team.find({ _id:AllegriTeams[i].team_id}, {_id:0, official_name:1})}
{ "official_name" : "Cag.00.xxx" }

// 6. Get length of "a"
> a.length
3
```

As an aside, **take note** that the `find()` function will *return a cursor*. Therefore, the values stored in your `a` array will be the cursor values. Consider using the `findOne()` function since it *returns a document*.

Again, check that your AllegriTeam variable has three array elements.

Comment: Yes you are right. The length of "a" is 3 in my case, too. But what can I do to save the cursor into a variable?

Comment: For example, 
> a[0]
{ "official_name" : "Juventus Football Club S.p.A." }
> a[1]
{ "official_name" : "Associazione Calcio Milan S.p.A" }
>a[2]

a[2] does not return the official name of Cagliari.

Comment: Are you trying to save the cursor in each array element? That does not make sense. What are you trying to achieve; what is your desired end result from querying the data?

Comment: My target is, simply, to show the elements that are in the array "a" after the for cycle. Maybe I found a way:
`> a.toString()
DBQuery: Progettino.team -> { "_id" : "Juv.26" },DBQuery: Progettino.team -> { "
_id" : "Mil.74" },DBQuery: Progettino.team -> { "_id" : "Cag.00" }`
I don't like a lot this kind of output. Are there any other solutions?